# Prometheus Targets Errors

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to retrieve information from Prometheus to the rest of the nodes of my cluster of Kubernetes.

[image]

I suspect the error is here and I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a quick question, are you running Prometheus as another Pod inside your cluster or is it a standalone service running in parallel to your nodes?

Comment: Es un pod dentro de mi cluster

Comment: Could you look at this [github issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2088)? Specifically at the resolution provided [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2088#issuecomment-255041283). Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: This has not helped me: /

Comment: I have already solved it, I have skipped SSL.

Comment: Hello @Al3jandro98, I'm glad to hear that, could you please add your answer and mark it as accepted? So if someone from the community had same issue he could find the answer there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, my problem was related to SSL, all I have done is skip the ssl and it works only with http.

To me putting the tsl_config section with this, the jobs that failed already work correctly for me:

```
tls_config:
      ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```

The important thing is this: **insecure_skip_verify: true** and the indentation that has to be as it is above.